# Can front end forms display recent entries?

Tags: forms, searchkit

Eg petition form page shows "Sue from Swindon just signed"
Contribution shows "Tim from Tottenham just donated $20"

Answer (score 4):

SearchKit is your friend! (... assuming your front-end is on the same site as Civi.  I don't think we have a good way to send SearchKit results to a remote site yet.)

In SearchKit, create a search:

[image]

Then create a List display and use the 'Rewrite text' option to add your additional text:

[image]

which generates:

[image]

Note that leading/trailing spaces in the rewrite box are stripped, so use `&nbsp;` to add a space at the start of the city and amount rewrites and tick 'Allow HTML'

(Currently saved on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ as 'Recent' until it gets rebuilt)

Comment: Brilliant Aiden & thanks for the Search Kit lesson - definitely my new friend! How would I add this to a wordpress page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal, you can create a block using drupal views and add the block to the form.

In WordPress combination of dataprocessor and shortcode in page may also work

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but this is certainly something you could add on, perhaps with CiviCRM Entity in Drupal, directly from the API or in an extension.

Comment: why that route rather than just a View?